# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''aws_account.aws_account_id'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in project

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I came across the following error, but I fail to see what is wrong:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''aws_account.aws_account_id'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\awsconfig\app\controllers\CRUDController.php on line 11

my join statement where the error is being thrown:

```
$query = DB::table('ec2_instance')->join('aws_account', 'aws_account.id', '=', 'ec2_instance.id')->select('ec2_instance.instance_id', 'ec2_instance.public_dns_name', 'ec2_instance.key_name','ec2_instance.instance_type','ec2_instance.launch_time',‌​'aws_account.aws_account_id')->get();
```

Comment: Looks more like the syntax for a `where()` than for a `join()`

Comment: This code won't generate that error. Have you posted the right line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got some junk characters there between the last `,` and `'`:

[image]